# Duplication issues when outer-merging with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, outer-join

I have an issue regarding duplication and pandas. I have two dataframes I must outer-join, for example, df 1 is given

| id | type | value1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 100 |
| 1 | b | 200 |

where *id==1* contains two types with different values and I want to join this with another df,

| id | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 300 |

I am merging the two using

```
df_merged = df1.merge(df2,how='outer',on='id')
```

The result is

| id | type | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 100 | 50 | 300 |
| 1 | b | 200 | 50 | 300 |

where it is clear that the value2 and value3 duplicates which may create issues if I e.g. wants to sum value2 or value3. Is there any way to merge and create e.g.

| id | type | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 100 | 50 | 300 |
| 1 | b | 200 | NaN | NaN |

or some type of other approach?

Thanks!

Comment: This is how the joining is designed to work. On a bigger scope, what are you trying to achieve? Why do you need this particular join?

Comment: What should happen if the 2 rows in df1 are **strictly** the same? Same id, type and value1.

Comment: To make statistics - the values are sensitive tax data. I don't want to count tax elements twice.

Comment: What don't you want to count twice? Wouldn't it make more sense to first groupby a certain column then join?

Comment: If values in df1 are identical, it should keep both values given that the type is different. If there are only one type in df1, there will only be 1 column hence not a problem. I simply don't want to duplicate "other" values when they merge.

Comment: I don't want to count value2 and value3 twice, but value1 from df1 is fine to be twice as they are from different types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could merge as you described, and then use:

```
df_merged.loc[df_merged.duplicated(subset=[dupe_cols]), [dupe_cols]] = np.nan
```

Comment: Hmmm, df_merged[df_merged.duplicated(subset=["value2","value3"])] = np.nan returns the entire row 2 as NaN.

Comment: Editted answer :) I've used .loc in order to specify the rows and columns to change